# How to avoid nested promises looping through firebase realtime database

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I'm new to firebase and node.js, and am writing a function which needs to loop through all elements in one section of the realtime databse (call it section B) and use data from another section as well (section A) per child. I'm running into issues with nested promises though, and am trying to understand how retrieving and joining data should be structured. Would really appreciate any guidance whether specific to the below or in general on how to avoid nested promises while joining data. Below are some simplified examples of the db and code.

```
root

  -A
     -id
        -1
           - animals
               -cats
               -dogs
           - othercategories ..
        -2 ..
        -3 ..
        -4 ..

   -B
     -id
        -1
           - activities
               -name
               -difficulty
               -team
        -4 ..
```

```js
/* the goal of this function is to loop through all of the ids in B 
and add an array of  [id, (sectionA>id>animals>dogs), (sectionB>id>activities>name)] 
to some list that will return, but it runs into an issue of nested promises
*/

function getInfo(){
  const dbRefB = db.ref('/B');
  const promises = [];

  var mainPromise = dbRefB.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
     snapshot.forEach((id) => {

          //this is a nested promise
          const dbRefAnimal = db.ref('/A/' + id.key + '/animals');
          var animalPromise = dbRefAnimal.once('value').then((snapshot) 
          => {
             return snapshot.child('dogs').val();
           });

         var activity = id.child(activities).child('name').val()

         const update = [id.key, animalPromise, activity]
         promises.push(update)
         }
      });
      return Promise.all(promises);
    }).catch((error) => {
    });

  return mainPromise

}
```

results: "avoid nesting promises. (promise/no nesting)"
expected: find a way to loop through sections of the firebase db while joining data from other sections without nested promises